# Calling Javascript form a ASP.NET Button located inside of an Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, updatepanel

I am using JQuery to toggle the visibility of a  in a webforms application.  I am using an update panel to suppress the postback when my  is clicked.  What I would like to do when this  is clicked is call the JQuery code that I use to toggle the  once the postback has completed.  What code(client-side or server-side) do I need to implement?  Thanks you.

Edit:

I don't just need to fire the toggle event when the postback has completed, but when server-side code says that the user's input is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this on server side:

```
if(<input is valid>)
{
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,this.Page.GetType(),"Toggle", "your javascript function call", true);
}
```

this will call your function when the postback completes

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

This is a JavaScRipt callback.  Just plug you handler in to toggle your code

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?  I'm unfamiliar with the PageRequestManager.

Comment: It's a script object injected into the browser for dealing with asynchronous calls when using an update panel.

Comment: This event fires when the page initially loads and seems to be disabling the other script I have in the page.